# File I/O in not generating file in project folder

Tags: java, java-io

The issue is i have a code for generating file, as given below

```
java.io.File jsonFile = new java.io.File("newjson.json");

    System.out.println(jsonFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        om.writeValue(jsonFile, categoryProducts);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("sorry we got little problem please try again later");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now when i run this program in output the **obsolute path** is as:

```
D:\eclips kepler\Eclipse-kepler\eclipse\newjson.json
```

this is the path of by **eclips IDE package**,
but my project path is:

```
D:\educational softwares\android workspace\webservicesForIndTadka
```

**the issue is why the file is generating in the location which is out of project context.**

**SOME WORKAROUND:**

Now when i give the file as

```
java.io.File jsonFile = new java.io.File("./json/newjson.json");
```

it says

```
D:\eclips kepler\Eclipse-kepler\eclipse\.\json\newjson.json
sorry we got little problem please try again later
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\json\newjson.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory.createJsonGenerator(JsonFactory.java:746)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:2048)
at com.techbloomer.services.ControllerServices.initApp(ControllerServices.java:120)
at com.techbloomer.controllers.DataControllers.initApp(DataControllers.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:212)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
```

Comment: the instruction java.io.File jsonFile = new java.io.File("./json/newjson.json"); doesn't create your file. It's not like that we create a file. see java Docs

Comment: You don't want the file in your project folder. The project won't be there when the software is deployed. You probably do want it in the current working directory, and that's where you're putting it. So there is probably no problem here to be solved.

Comment: @user230137.. actually i already have my file in my project but the problem is its not pointing to that file its pointing some whare else....

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the file in the project folder, not in the class path folder. So you need to specify the absolute path to file. Secondly, you need to close output stream as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try anyone of the fllowing:

1.Mention the full path in your file constructor.

2.Or you are going to write something in your file right?? Just do this..

FileOutputStream jsonfile = new FileOutputStream("newjson.json");

which will create the file in your current working project.